# Analytic continuation of the power series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $f(z) := \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n z^n$ with $a_n \in {\Bbb C}$ be a power series ring such that the radius of convergence is equal to $1$.

Suppose that for the chosen point $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha| = 1$, i.e. a point on the unit circle $C$, the limit $\underset{z \to \alpha}{\mathrm{lim}} \, f(z)$ always coincides with the fixed finite value, which we denote by $f(\alpha)$, under *any* path inside $C$.

### Q. Under this condition, is it possible to analytically continue $f(z)$ at $z = \alpha$? That is, $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $z = \alpha$?

Comment: no - take $f(z)=\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{z^{2^n}}{2^n}$ trivially $f(z) \to 1, z \to 1, |z| \le 1$ but $f$ is not continuable at $1$ since otherwise $f'$ would be and that is the well-known series that is not continuable at any point beyond the unit circle